What is some recommended software to write a chess book? Chess icons, board position layouts, etc
I am writing a small puzzle book for a few friends and myself. I am curious what software is available to write a chess book including board positions, chess fonts, page layouts, book template guide, etc.

Hello, why do you think such software exists? It's not like thousands of people write chess books. You're better off looking for something that helps with just drawings, the rest is up to you to style. Also, is it supposed to be free? For what systems? For commercial usage?

See this question Chess software for writing books from 2018 on chess.SE

You can use Lichess tools. You can change the chess icons and the board in the settings (⚙).

Analysis Board, example
Board Editor
Import Game in Portable Game Notation (PGN)

Analysis (example) :
Screenshot current position
Download PGN

The same tools are available in PyChess, with some differences.
